# Can't get Xdebug to work (mac+PhpStorm+Laradock+Xdebug)

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, xdebug, laradock

I need to debug the code in my local environment.Accurately speaking, is a Laradock in my mac. But I tried it many times and failed.

```
Mac version MoJave 10.14.2
Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4
Docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad01
Laradock version(commit id) a03c225e279910b9393b5e95fbffe5081b9e5a95
PhpStorm version  2018.1.1 Build #PS-181.4445.72
```

Xdebug status :

```
PHP 7.2.15 (cli) (built: Feb 21 2019 23:48:47) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.15, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.7.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2019, by Derick Rethans
```

phpinfo :
[image: xdebug info in phpinfo web page]

workspace/xdebug.ini :
[image: workspace/xdebug.ini]

php-fpm/xdebug.ini :
[image: php-fpm/xdebug.ini]

docker-composer ps :
[image: docker-composer ps]

Xdebug setting in PhpStorm :
[image: xdebug in PhpStorm setting]

Service setting in PhpStorm :
[image: service setting in PhpStorm]

Remote debug setting in PhpStorm :
[image: remote debug setting in PhpStorm]

PHP Web Page setting in PhpStorm :
[image: php web page setting in PhpStorm]

All of the above are my configuration information.

Let's take a look at the port information

```
➜  laradock git:(master) lsof -i:9001
```

Started Listening for PHP Debug connections

```
➜  laradock git:(master) lsof -i:9001
COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
phpstorm 268 lightWay   56u  IPv4 0xa71f266f59200b2d      0t0  TCP *:etlservicemgr (LISTEN)
```

When I type in the URL and press the Enter key, the window will jump to PhpStorm

PhpStorm Like this :
[image: phpstorm]

When I click 'Step Over(F8)' PhpStorm Like this:
[image: debug failed]

Debugging can't go on and Chrome is waiting state:
[image: chrome]

Port information :

```
➜  laradock git:(master) lsof -i:9001
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
phpstorm  268 lightWay   56u  IPv4 0xa71f266f59200b2d      0t0  TCP *:etlservicemgr (LISTEN)
phpstorm  268 lightWay   71u  IPv4 0xa71f266f59f45e2d      0t0  TCP localhost:etlservicemgr->localhost:51955 (CLOSE_WAIT)
phpstorm  268 lightWay   73u  IPv4 0xa71f266f669227ad      0t0  TCP localhost:etlservicemgr->localhost:55017 (ESTABLISHED)
com.docke 648 lightWay   30u  IPv4 0xa71f266f592027ad      0t0  TCP localhost:55017->localhost:etlservicemgr (ESTABLISHED)
```

If I end my browser access, I got :

[image: debug failed]

Port information :

```
➜  laradock git:(master) lsof -i:9001
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
phpstorm  268 lightWay   56u  IPv4 0xa71f266f59200b2d      0t0  TCP *:etlservicemgr (LISTEN)
phpstorm  268 lightWay   71u  IPv4 0xa71f266f59f45e2d      0t0  TCP localhost:etlservicemgr->localhost:51955 (CLOSE_WAIT)
phpstorm  268 lightWay   73u  IPv4 0xa71f266f669227ad      0t0  TCP localhost:etlservicemgr->localhost:55017 (ESTABLISHED)
com.docke 648 lightWay   30u  IPv4 0xa71f266f592027ad      0t0  TCP localhost:55017->localhost:etlservicemgr (ESTABLISHED)
```

Nothing changes and Xdebug Connection is not broken.

But if I click 'Stop index.php (F12)' my browser request will end.

port like this :

```
➜  laradock git:(master) lsof -i:9001
COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
phpstorm 268 lightWay   17u  IPv4 0xa71f266f68032e2d      0t0  TCP *:etlservicemgr (LISTEN)
```

I feel that PhpStorm has not received a request from the browser or Xdebug.

How do I get the Xdebug work?

Oh, yes, sometimes I can get tips from PhpStorm
[image: tips]

But I have already configured it in the `./laradock/.env` file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated... If I need to supply more info, I will gladly do so.

Comment: What's your PhpStorm version?

Comment: Try to set `xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1`

Comment: @LazyOne PhpStorm 2018.1.1 Build #PS-181.4445.72, built on April 9, 2018

Comment: You are using Xdebug 2.7. That version had some changes in its protocol .. so you need PhpStorm 2018.3 or newer in order to work with Xdebug 2.7. Alternatively, downgrade Xdebug to 2.6.x.

Comment: @ LazyOne  This is amazing! ! !  I never thought that this trouble is about XDEBUG version, thank you bro

Answer (score -1):

My setup isn't using PHPStorm but try changing the following settings to match:

In **workspace/xdebug.ini** set:

```
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

And in **php-fpm/xdebug.ini** set:

```
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal
```

Be sure to rebuild your docker container (including php-fpm) to include any config changes *- this was the missing key for me*:

```
docker-compose down
docker-compose build mysql nginx php-fpm
docker-compose up -d mysql nginx php-fpm
```